# Validar dados de uma objeto com DataAnnotations C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dataannotations

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte classe de Entidade marcada por Data Annotations:

```
public class Cargo
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name ="Código")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false, ErrorMessage = "A descrição do cargo é obrigatória")]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

}
```

Tenho o seguinte método que captura os erros da classe:

```
public static IEnumerable<ValidationResult> getErrosValidacao(object objeto)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> resultadoValidacao = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var contexto = new ValidationContext(objeto, null, null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(objeto, contexto, resultadoValidacao, true);
        return resultadoValidacao;
    }
```

Por fim tenho o seguinte método que valida o *insert* no banco:

```
public void ValidarInsercao(Cargo cargo)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cargo.Descricao))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("A descrição do cargo não tem um valor válido.");
        }

        objCargo.Inserir(cargo);//tenta inserir no banco de dados

    }
```

Eu gostaria de validar o objeto **cargo** pelas regras do *DataAnnotations* e caso houvesse erros ele lançasse uma exceção, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemente uma classe que é responsável em verificar se o seu `Model` é válido:

```
public sealed class ModelValid
{                                 
    public ICollection<ValidationResult> ValidationResults { get; private set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; private set; }
    public ModelValid(object model)            
    {
        ValidationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        IsValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, 
            new ValidationContext(model), 
            ValidationResults, true);            
    }
    public ModelValid(object model, bool throwIfExists)
        :this(model)
    {
        if (throwIfExists) ThrowException();
    }
    public void ThrowException()
    {               
        throw new ValidationException(ErrorMessages());
    }  
    public string ErrorMessages()
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        if (!IsValid)
        {
            if (ValidationResults != null &&
                ValidationResults.Count > 0)
            {                              
                IEnumerator<ValidationResult> results =
                    ValidationResults.GetEnumerator();
                while (results.MoveNext())
                {
                    ValidationResult vr = results.Current;
                    message += vr.ErrorMessage + System.Environment.NewLine;
                }                    
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

#### Como utilizar:

No evento `Click` de um `Button`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cargo cargo = new Cargo { };
        ModelValid modelValid = new ModelValid(cargo, true);
        objCargo.Inserir(cargo);            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Se o `model` for válido, a próxima execução seria do `Inserir`, e se tiver algum problema entra em ação `try` `catch` com os problemas do `model`. Não sei se lançar um exceção assim seria adequado, mas, se não quiser que apareça erros de exceção, mas, *Mensagens de Erros* (`MessageBox`) a classe pode ser trabalhada da seguinte forma:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

    Cargo cargo = new Cargo { };

    ModelValid modelValid = new ModelValid(cargo);
    if (modelValid.IsValid)
    {
        objCargo.Inserir(cargo);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(modelValid.ErrorMessages(), "Error");
    }          

}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse link tem um exemplo on-line rodando em [***Console Application***](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U2hw07) somente pra demonstração, sendo que esse código foi testado e funciona como perguntado em `Windows Forms`.

**Referencias:**

- [Classe ValidationResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Classe ValidationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Classe ValidationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método Validator.TryValidateObject (Object, ValidationContext, ICollection, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Irei tentar implementar aqui amigo assim que puder marco como resolvido!

Comment: Amigo sua classe funcionou perfeitamente e não poderia ser melhor, muito obrigado!